# sort order of list gets rearranged every page load

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint, lodash, office365-restapi

i created a custom top menu for our sharepoint page. code as follows:
The code is basically iterating through the list of menuitems then getting the submenu items from another sharepoint list then i'd display the menu. it works but every time i load the page, the menu items always have a random order, i suspect it's because of the ajax call i used inside the foreach. but i'm currently stuck on what to do next.

note: topMenuItems have the correct sort order but when i am displaying the menu, the top menu always get rearranged randomly.

```
    _.forEach(topMenuItems, function (menuItem) {

        var subMenuUrl =  //RESTAPI URL
        $.ajax({
            url: subMenuUrl,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
               var smItems = data.d.results;
                var name = menuItem.MenuTitle;
                var menuId = menuItem.ID;
                var url = menuItem.Navigation_x0020_URL;
                var urlMain = '';

                SubmenuNames = "<ul>";

               _.forEach(smItems, function (subMenuItem) {

                       // code for displaying the menu goes here
               });


            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }   
        });
 });
```

the console log would be something like:

topMenu ID Items: 1,2,3,4,5,6

but when i log the top menu ids inside the  _.forEach(smItems, function (subMenuItem) {

```
                   // code for displaying the menu goes here
           });
```

i get random orders like : 1,2,5,3,4,6.

Comment: are you worried about the topmenu items being displayed in random order evertime, or the submenu items?

Comment: @VineetDesai im worried about the top menu items being displayed randomly :)

Comment: You can add a new column (integer type) "SortOrder" to your list. Give the desired sort order for the items by adding appropriate value in the column. In your rest query add $orderby='<name of the sort order column>'

Comment: maybe it helps `_.sortBy(smItems);`

Comment: @VineetDesai i do have a sortorder column in my list. and my rest url have orderby at the end of  my url string

Comment: The issue is because of asynchronous nature of the ajax calls. Use jquery promises to get the final HTML result along with sequence for each top menu and store it in array. Then use $when.apply() to resolve promise array and sort the result by sequence.

Comment: @VineetDesai will try that one! thanks!

Comment: Thanks @VineetDesai, what you said worked@ :)

Comment: @gerine Please mark the comment as useful to help others in community. Thanks:-)